# dropdownlist in GridView Data Bound not behaving correctly ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT Equipment.* ,cast(EquipmentId as varchar(100)) + ' ' + EquipmentName as Name
FROM Equipment 
WHERE Equipment.EquipmentCategoryID = @EquipmentCategoryID 
AND (Equipment.EquipmentSubCategoryID = @EquipmentSubCategoryID 
OR (@EquipmentSubCategoryID is null OR @EquipmentSubCategoryID = '' ))
```

In SQL Server it is behaving as expected. When `@EquipmentCategoryId` is 12 and `@EquipmentSubCategoryID` is null It returns all the values I want. And when `@EquipmentCategoryId` is 12 and `@EquipmentSubCategoryID` is another number it returns the smaller amount of rows which is also what I want.

In an ASP.NET dropdownlist in a GridView it is not behaving as expected, returning all the rows for each `dropdownlist` in the `GridView`, even though the `@EquipmentSubCategoryID` has different numbers, that work in SQL Server. The `dropdownlist` is bound like this.

```
protected void ServiceFormsGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {                
         HiddenField EquipmentCategoryIDHF = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentCategoryIDHF");
         HiddenField EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF");
         DropDownList EquipmentDD = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentDD");
         EquipmentDS.SelectParameters["EquipmentCategoryID"].DefaultValue = EquipmentCategoryIDHF.Value;              
         EquipmentDS.SelectParameters["EquipmentSubCategoryID"].DefaultValue = EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF.Value; 
         EquipmentDD.Items.Clear();
         EquipmentDD.Items.Add(new ListItem());
         EquipmentDD.DataBind();  
    }
}
```

I can confirm that each time through the method that the HiddenFields are displaying the correct values but the `ServiceFormsGV` `GridView` has all the rows in each `DropDownList`.
The GridView is as follows.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ServiceFormsGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ServiceFormID,EquipmentCategoryID1" DataSourceID="ServiceFormsDS" OnDataBound="ServiceFormsGV_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="ServiceFormsGV_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Id">
          <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="EquipmentDD" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="EquipmentDS" DataTextField="EquipmentName" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                    DataValueField="EquipmentID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EquipmentDD_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

And in the SQLDataSource I have

```
CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False"
```

which is necessary.

I have tested the query in Configure Data Source and it behaves as expected.

[image: Testing in ASP.NET SqlDataSource]

Comment: Is it only one sqlDataSource you are using for all the dropdownlist?

Comment: Yes I am only using 1 sqlDataSource for the dropdownlist. Though I have other dropdowns in the gridview which seem to be working

Comment: Other dropdowns also load different items in in each rows of gridview? Did you try debugging and see if correct values are being passed to the sqlDataSource?

Comment: Yes the correct values are being passed in. I tested that.

Comment: Are you sure that value for parameter `@EquipmentSubCategoryID` is not NULL or blank string every time? Also I tried the query you shared in SSMS and I see that when `@EquipmentSubCategoryID` is having a value the query does not return any data.

Comment: Actually the query works fine in SSMS. Thanks for your interest in helping me. I have provided a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this behavior is `SqlDataSource` being used as DataSource for the dropdownlists inside the GridView.

During DataGridView_RowDataBound event you are changing default values of the parameters of `SqlDataSource` and rebinding the dropdownlist of the row. When you change  the Default values of parameters the outcome of the query execution by `SqlDataSource` impacts all the dropdownlists so eventually all the dropdownlists will have the query result generated by the values passed by the last row of the gridview. That is why you get the same result in all the dropdownlists of the grid.

You need to run the query everytime and retrieve the result and bind it separately to each dropdownlist without using any common datasource among them.

While the solution you found is works with no issues, it would require a SQL connection to be opened and run query against the db for each Row of DataGridView.

The approach I suggest is to retrieve the all the rows from the Equipment table and store them as a collection of entities at page level and then during rowDataBound event filter the collection for the current Category and SubCategory and bind the filtered result to the dropdown list.

Following is the entity Equipment

```
public class Equipment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", Id, Name);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Page_load populate the collection of Equipment by retrieving all the rows from Equipment table in the database.

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    private List<Equipment> equipments;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        equipments = new List<Equipment>();

        var commandText = "SELECT EquipmentId, EquipmentName, CategoryId, SubCategoryId FROM Equipment";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LocalDevDb;User id=sa;Password=Password1"))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var equipment = new Equipment
                        {
                            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            Name = reader.GetString(1),
                            CategoryId = reader.GetString(2),
                            SubCategoryId = reader.GetString(3),
                        };

                        equipments.Add(equipment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Filter this collection based on the CategoryId and SubCategoryId and bind the result to the DropDown.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList EquipmentDD = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dropDownList");

        HiddenField EquipmentCategoryIDHF = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentCategoryIDHF");
        HiddenField EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF");

        var categoryId = EquipmentCategoryIDHF.Value;
        var subCategoryId = EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF.Value;

        Func<Equipment, bool> criteria;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subCategoryId))
        {
            criteria = criteria = equip => equip.CategoryId == categoryId && equip.SubCategoryId == subCategoryId;
        }
        else
        {
            criteria = equip => equip.CategoryId == categoryId;
        }

        var list = equipments.Where(criteria).ToList();

        EquipmentDD.DataSource = list;
        EquipmentDD.DataBind();
        EquipmentDD.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem());

    }
}
```

Here in my example, CategoryId and SubCategoryId columns are created with String datatype. You need to change them to appropriate if they are different than columns of your table.

This should help you solve your issue.

Comment: While my solution is correct and solved my problem I believe your solution is more efficient and that is why I have selected yours as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is that the `SqlDataSource` needs to to be in the `GridView` for the row. So in the same place as the `DropDownList` in the `ItemTemplate`. That wasy the SqlDataSource is updated for each row in the RowDataBound method.

```
protected void ServiceFormsGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {                
         HiddenField EquipmentCategoryIDHF = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentCategoryIDHF");
         HiddenField EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF");
         SqlDataSource EquipmentDS = (SqlDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentDS");
         DropDownList EquipmentDD = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("EquipmentDD");
         EquipmentDS.SelectParameters["EquipmentCategoryID"].DefaultValue = EquipmentCategoryIDHF.Value;              
         EquipmentDS.SelectParameters["EquipmentSubCategoryID"].DefaultValue = EquipmentSubCategoryIDHF.Value; 
         EquipmentDD.Items.Clear();
         EquipmentDD.Items.Add(new ListItem());
         EquipmentDD.DataBind();  
    }
}

<asp:GridView ID="ServiceFormsGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ServiceFormID,EquipmentCategoryID1" DataSourceID="ServiceFormsDS" OnDataBound="ServiceFormsGV_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="ServiceFormsGV_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Id">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="EquipmentDD" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="EquipmentDS" 
                   DataTextField="EquipmentName" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                      DataValueField="EquipmentID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EquipmentDD_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="EquipmentDS" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX %>"  SelectCommand="SELECT Equipment.* ,cast(EquipmentId as varchar(100)) + ' ' + EquipmentName as Name  FROM Equipment WHERE Equipment.EquipmentCategoryID = @EquipmentCategoryID AND (Equipment.EquipmentSubCategoryID = @EquipmentSubCategoryID OR (@EquipmentSubCategoryID is null OR @EquipmentSubCategoryID = '' ) )">
                   <SelectParameters>
                      <asp:Parameter Name="EquipmentCategoryID" />
                      <asp:Parameter Name="EquipmentSubCategoryID" />
                   </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
           </ItemTemplate>
```

It makes sense and it works.

Comment: I was preparing a solution but you found it first. :) . This is also a solution. If you do not want to open connection and query database for each row of GridView you can think of retrieving all the equipmenets in page_load and create a list and filter that list in rowDataBound event. Let me know if you want me to provide that solution.

Comment: Yes I would like to see that solution. Thanks.

Comment: I just posted the solution.